# Escalade vs escalate

Tags: verbs

Our company uses project management software called Jira. In Jira you can mark one issue so that it 'escalades' another, or 'is escaladed' by another. I think that is something like 'cause', but you can set 'cause' or 'is caused', so they are different.

And I find the meme 'that escalated quickly', and looks like it has a similar meaning to escalade.

Can anyone tell me what *escalade* means in 'one issue escalades another'? Can I use *escalate* instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as if *escalade* is being used in place of *escalate*. The only meaning the OED give for *escalade* is ‘To climb up and get over or enter (a wall, rampart, etc.) by means of ladders; to scale.’ *Escalate*, on the other hand, can be used figuratively to mean ‘To increase or develop by successive stages’.

Comment: Are you saying that is an misuse?

Comment: @fossilet: _Misuse_ is a word I try to avoid. I can only say that this is the first time I've seen _escalade_ in this context, and that I wouldn't use it that way myself.

Comment: @fossilet: I think it may be more of a typo. Looking at all the Jira documentation by Atlassian, it refers to 'escalating an issue' and 'to automatically escalate an issue' etc.

Comment: @Hmobius: Yes, that should be escalate after I search in the Jira documentation.

Comment: I’m with you on *escalade* being for scaling ladders. We have a two-million–acre national monument in southern Utah called [Grand Staircase–Escalante](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Staircase-Escalante_National_Monument), which is ironically named. It features the staggeringly awesome geological feature named the *Grand Staircase*, and its other name, *Escalante* makes you think of climbing it. This is accidental: *Escalante* is named for a nearby hamlet, itself named for a Spanish explorer. But philologically it is something of a happy accident, as these things are sometimes called.